# from weighted average to single values

Tags: average, inverse

think about when you're computing a weighted average: you do something like

W = sum(amount*weight) / sum(weight)

Now I need to find every amount (amount0, amount1.....) starting from knowing the value of W and every single weight. Is this possible? I'm trying to find out an algorithm.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think this is impossible given just weighted average and each weight

Answer (score 4):

It corresponds to $$w_1x+w_2y+...+w_Nz=W$$ with known coefficients $w_i$. Given W and $w_i$, clearly there is no unique solution for this system but multiple solutions..

Comment: What I'm trying to do here is to find an average weighted margin. Each amount for me is a final sell price, so from W I can calculate sum(amounts) or I can take some hints from purchase prices..I know there's no a unique solution, but in addition I have some max min limit for each product price..

Comment: Yes I see. There is no unique solution but if you have a set of equations then you have a solution based on some "nice" criterion even if you have more equations than unknowns. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system  Moreover I can suggest to have a look compressive sensing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corollary I think they will help at any case

Answer (score 3):

As others have remarked, this is impossible. However if we are given a number of weighted averages, and the weights used to calculate each average, then we *may* be able to determine the original values. In general though we will need lots of weights to find the values, so it's really only an academic exercise.

So suppose there are $n$ values $a_1, ... , a_n$ that we want to find. We are given $m$ weighted averages:
$$
     w_{11} a_1 + ... + w_{1n} a_n = W_1 \\
     w_{21} a_1 + ... + w_{2n} a_n = W_2 \\
     ...\\
     w_{m1} a_1 + ... + w_{mn} a_n = W_m
$$
First we require $m$ to be at least as large as $n$. We can write this in matrix form:
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
   w_{11} & w_{12} & ... &w_{1n} \\
   w_{21} & w_{22} & ... &w_{2n} \\
   .& .& ... & .\\
   w_{m1} & w_{m2} & ... &w_{mn} \\
  \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
   a_1 \\ a_2 \\ . \\ a_n
  \end{pmatrix} = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
   W_1 \\ W_2 \\ . \\ W_m
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
Now we need to solve this equation to get the matrix/vector
$$
A =  \begin{pmatrix}
   a_1 \\ a_2 \\ . \\ a_n
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
on its own. There is a criteria for solving this from linear algebra: if we can find $n$ *[linearly independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence)* rows in the matrix of $w$'s then we will be able to solve for the $a$'s. If we can't find $n$ linearly independent rows then we won't be able to solve for the $a$'s.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on how to do it when you have two values. 
There are two naturally occurring isotopes of chlorine.
35Cl has a mass of 34.9689 amu.
37Cl has a mass of 36.9659 amu. 
Determine the abundance of each isotope.

From the periodic table the given mass is 35.453

The sum of the percentage of the abundances is 100% or 1.00 since we use decimals i.e. 75% = .75 
Set one abundance to x and the other abundance to 1 - x.

(34.9689 * x) + (36.9659 * (1-x)) = 35.453
34.9689X + 36.9659 - 36.9659x = 35.453

solve for x.

x = .7576 so the abundance of 35Cl with mass of 34.9689 amu is 75.76%
and the other isotope is 24.24%

For reference:
http://www.chemteam.info/Mole/AvgAtomicWt-Reverse.html